# STL Priority Queue Non-Class Type Compilation Error

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I thought I had this figured out, but I guess I was wrong. I was under the impression that the first element in '<...>' is the type that is to be stored in the queue, the second is the container type (the choices being 'vector' or 'dequeue') and the third is the class that overloads the '()' operator for comparison. Based on this, I think the following code should compile, but it does not :(

```
std::priority_queue<uint32_t*, std::vector<uint32_t*>, edgeComparator> q();

uint32_t* nodeEdge = new uint32_t[2];
nodeEdge[0] = startN;
nodeEdge[1] = 0;

q.push(nodeEdge);
```

'edgeComparator' is defined as follows:

```
class edgeComparator
{
   public:
      bool operator() (const uint32_t*& lhs, const uint32_t*& rhs) const
      {
         return (lhs[1]>rhs[1]);
      }
};
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
./Graph.cpp: In member function `void Graph::findShortestPath()':
./Graph.cpp:148: error: request for member `push' in `q', which is of non-class type `std::priority_queue<uint32_t*, std::vector<uint32_t*, std::allocator<uint32_t*> >, edgeComparator> ()()'
```

Worse yet, I also get this error when trying 'q.empty()'

```
./Graph.cpp:150: error: request for member `empty' in `q', which is of non-class type `std::priority_queue<uint32_t*, std::vector<uint32_t*, std::allocator<uint32_t*> >, edgeComparator> ()()'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had:

```
std::priority_queue<uint32_t*, std::vector<uint32_t*>, edgeComparator> q();
```

But instead, you should use:

```
std::priority_queue<uint32_t*, std::vector<uint32_t*>, edgeComparator> q;
```

The first version declares a *function* named `q`, that takes no arguments, and returns a value of type `std::priority_queue<...>`.

The second version declares a *variable* named `q`, of type `std::priority_queue<...>`, which is default-initialised.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I thought 'SomeClass sc();' would call the constructor for 'SomeClass' with no arguments, this is not so apparantly? I've used similar notation with arguments provided to initialize things before.

Comment: You do use that syntax to specify _one or more_ arguments to the constructor. But when using _zero_ arguments, you must not use the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! That seems very inconsistent, but I'm certain I'll never forget that. I'll just add to the list of things I don't like about C++ lol.

Comment: Many of C++'s syntax issues came from the fact that it needed to maintain backward compatibility with C. In this specific instance, C already used the syntax `int f();` to declare a function named `f` returning `int`. So C++ couldn't reuse that syntax for something else.

Comment: Inconsistency depends on context. `int f(); double g(); my_class h();` It would be inconsistent if `h` defined an object but `f` and `g` did not.